# Rotating on multiple axis with three.js

Tags: javascript, mobile, 3d, three.js

I'm experimenting with three.js and the deviceorientation event. I'm rotating a cube with my phone's accelerometer, using the technique used in the [THREE.DeviceOrientationState plugin](http://joshondesign.com/p/books/canvasdeepdive-examples/WebGL/vendor/threex/docs/THREEx.DeviceOrientationState.html). Basically the coordinates from the deviceorientation event angles are converted to radians and applied to a meshes' rotation coordinates (mesh.rotation.x, etc). Pretty basic.

This technique works fine as long as the phone is not rotated more than 90 degrees, but once it hits 90 degrees the rotation get messed up and the cube basically "flips". Not sure how else to describe it. Also, rotation works perfectly when rotating on only one axis, but as soon as two or more axis are involved and the phone is rotated more than 90 degrees we have problems.

Basically I need to know how to combine more than one rotation angle so that the cube rotates with the phone no matter how much the phone is rotated. The cube should always mimic the rotation of the phone. (I know, it's a bit weird to do that since you can't see the phone screen when it has been rotated so much, but bear with me, I have a plan.)

I thought maybe I was hitting gimbal lock, so tried using quaternions, but I get the same results. To be honest, I'm a little embarrassed to be asking this question. It has been a while since I did any 3D programming, but I feel like I should know how to do this.

Here's some example code. What else do I need to do to combine the rotation angles?

```
$(window).on('deviceorientation', function(e) {
    var x = (!e.originalEvent.beta  ? 0 : e.originalEvent.beta) * Math.PI / 180;
    var y = (!e.originalEvent.gamma ? 0 : e.originalEvent.gamma) * Math.PI / 180;
    var z = (!e.originalEvent.alpha ? 0 : (e.originalEvent.alpha - 180)) * Math.PI / 180;

    cube.rotation.x = x;
    cube.rotation.y = y;
    cube.rotation.z = z;
});
```

UPDATE: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/5y99U/) that illustrates the issue. It has been modified to use the DeviceOrientationControls feature, which is now included in three.js. You'll see that the problem persists. Basically I need the cube to mimic the orientation of the phone exactly, no matter how much I turn the phone.

UPDATE 2: I changed the shape in the above jsfiddle from a cube to a 3d rectangle that is in the shape of a phone. I think it's easier to see what's happening with a rectangle than a cube.

Comment: This has been implemented in the three.js r.67 dev branch. See http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js,  http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html and http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/css3d_panorama_deviceorientation.html.

Comment: Thanks -- that's really good to know. I tried it out, but I'm still not getting exactly the results I'm looking for. I create a webgl cube and assign it to DeviceOrientationControls, but I get the same results. Rotating the phone beyond 90 degrees causes the cube to go out of whack. What I need is for the cube to mimic the phone orientation exactly. It almost works, but not quite.

Comment: Can you modify your post using the three.js controls, and post a simple live example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Sure thing. See my update with a JS Fiddle. I included the entire DeviceOrientationControls in the fiddle, since I don't have a CDN with it. I'm also using a CND with Three.js v 61, but it seems to work fine. If you view this fiddle on a phone you'll see what I mean. Rotation only works up to a point, then I believe the axis start to get a bit confused. I ened the cube to always be in exactly the same position as the phone. Also, I am not taking into consideration screen orientation. I have locked the screen orientation on my phone. (Could that be part of the problem?)

Comment: Please use the dev version of three.js r.67dev. I am unable to reproduce your problem. Does [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7508542/three.js/r67dev/examples/css3d_panorama_deviceorientation.html) work for you?

Comment: I don't have a CDN with r.67, but can find one. I don't think the version is the issue, though. The example project you gave above works fine, but this is the camera rotating, whereas I want to rotate a 3D object. Think of the phone as a controller -- as it changes orientation the cube mimics the exact orientation. So if the phone is lying on a table with it's front facing up, the 3D objects "front" is also facing "up". If you rotate to the left on the Z axis, the object does the same thing. If you turn the phone upside down, the 3D object's "front" is facing down, etc. Make sense?

Comment: Oh!.. and that's what you said in your first sentence. :/  The three.js controls are designed to be used with the "object" being the camera. The camera is the only object that faces by default down it's negative z-axis. All other objects face by default up their positive z-axis. This should be dooable...

Comment: OK so its just a matter of adapting the camera code to  use apositive z-axis? I suppose quaternions are still the way to go. Am I right?

Comment: Quaternions, definitely. I experimented with [_this_](http://jsfiddle.net/5y99U/3/) using the dev branch and an iPhone and I did not see any unusual symptoms. No changes were made to the controls code. I did not have a lot of time to invest in it, however.... Maybe you can figure it out. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Your JSFiddle doesn't quite work 100% for me (at least with my nexus 5), but it's a step in the right direction, and better than what I had before. I'll see if I can get it to work. Thanks VERY much for your help.

Comment: It took me a mind-bending 12 hours just to the the dev67 code working! Try removing `quaternion.multiply( q1 );` and resize your cube w/h/d  like so: `THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 10, 100 )`.

Comment: Yep, it's basically working now. Sweet. The only thing I need to figure out now is how to lock the rotation to a certain direction (say, due north, for example). Right now rotation only works as expected when I'm facing a certain direction. If I rotate my body to the left or right rotation is thrown off. I guess this is essentially the same problem as combining local and orbital rotation, if that makes sense. Any ideas off the top of your head?

Comment: The device alpha param is not necessarily in sync with the compass directions -- it can be relative. You will have to google that topic -- then share your results, please. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49863/discussion-between-jude-osborn-and-westlangley)